# Visual Studio highlighting source code in bold

Tags: visual-studio-2005

While editing HTML/ASPX/ASCX etc in visual studio 2005; whenever I select an html tag, visual studio highlights the entire tag in black and bold; the black I'm not so fussed about but the bold changes the length of the line and really messes up the formatting.

Is there a way to disable this?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In VS2010: Select menu `Tools - Options`, select `Environment / Fonts and Colors`, look for `Brace Matching (Rectangle)` in the Display items list. Uncheck the `Bold` checkbox and click on `Ok` to confirm.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd consider them braces but this does fix the issue;

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In VS2008, go to the Tools >> Options menu, expand the Environment category in the treeview and select Fonts and Colors. Under Display Items, select HTML Attribute Name and uncheck the "Bold" checkbox.